# My Multi Theft Auto client doesn't detect VRAM properly, how could I solve this?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I'm trying to play Multi Theft Auto: San Andreas, but the custom GUI can't render most of the time, because it says, it's out of VRAM. As you'll see the detected VRAM is around 250MB, but I have 6GB, which should be sufficient for this game. All my drivers are up-to-date.

What could I do, to increase the amount of detected VRAM?

**Edit 1:** Using the built-in scripting interface, I checked, that the used GPU is my discrete GPU ("NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design"), and the detected VRAM is 256 MB.

**Edit 2:** I suspect, that the game can't work with cards, that have more than 4 GB vRAM. Could this be true? Can I temporarily decrease the capacity of my vRAM?

**Debug information:**
[MTADiag](https://pastebin.mtasa.com/755529500)

[image: showmemstat screenshot]

Comment: Seems like the game is only detecting your integrated GPU, which has only 240 MB dedicated VRAM. I believe your driver should give you an option to force using your discrete GPU instead of the integrated one. By the way, I can't see your screenshot. You can upload your screenshot to this site by clicking on the "Image" button when you edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
I tried setting both the global preferred GPU and the application specific GPU in the Nvidia Control panel to the discrete GPU, but nothing has changed.
Added screenshot to the post :D